# Copy sub-directories in c

Tags: c, file, directory, copy

Does anyone know how to copy a directory, including all subdirectories across to another folder
The code I've written so far copies over text files and directories, but it doesn't copy all the sub-directories. Before going any further, I have seen questions like this before, but there don't cover what I need to know, or there covered in other languages.

Sorry if my code is a mess.

Anyway, here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 4096
#define COPYMODE 0644
#define FILE_MODE S_IRWXU

DIR * directory;
struct dirent * entry;
DIR * directoryTwo;
struct dirent * entryTwo;
struct stat info;

// copyFile

void copyFile(const char * src, const char * dst)
{
    FILE * file1, *file2;
    file1 = fopen(src, "r");
    if(file1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Cannot open source file");
        fclose(file1);
        exit(-1);
    }

    file2 = fopen(dst, "w");

    if(file2 == NULL) {
        perror("cannot open destination file");
        fclose(file2);
        exit(-1);
    }

    char currentchar;
    while((currentchar = getc(file1)) != EOF) {
        fputc(currentchar, file2);
    }

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
}

void goThoughFile(const char * srcFilePath, const char * dst)
{
    char srcFile[260];
    char dstFile[260];

    directory = opendir(srcFilePath);
    if(directory == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
    {
        if(strstr(entry->d_name, "DS_Store") || strstr(entry->d_name, ".localized") ||
                strstr(".", &entry->d_name[0]) || strstr("..", &entry->d_name[0]))
            continue;

        else if(entry->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            sprintf(srcFile, "%s/%s", srcFilePath, entry->d_name);
            sprintf(dstFile, "%s/%s", dst, entry->d_name);
            copyFile(srcFile, dstFile);
        }

        if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            chdir(dst);
            mkdir(entry->d_name, S_IRWXU);
            sprintf(dstFile, "%s%s/%s", dst, entry->d_name, "/..");
            chdir(dstFile);
            mkdir(entry->d_name, S_IRWXU);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    goThoughFile(someFilePath, anotherFilePath);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive directory copying in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177378/recursive-directory-copying-in-c)

Comment: I did see that post, but how would you use that to copy the directories as you come across them?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve using `struct dirent` can not be guaranteed to work.

You are checking `if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR)` the file for type Directory, but if you read the manual of `readdir(3)` it clearly says in the comment of structure that it is not supported by all filesystem types.

```
On Linux, the dirent structure is defined as follows:

       struct dirent {
           ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
           off_t          d_off;       /* not an offset; see NOTES */
           unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
           unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                          by all filesystem types */
           char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
       };
```

You have to use `getdents()`.
For more clarification please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958040/checking-if-a-dir-entry-returned-by-readdir-is-a-directory-link-or-file).